# Angular libraries to implement full calendar scheduler

Tags: angular6

what are the best libraries to implement Angular 6 full-calendar (scheduler)- the best options and advantages of each one ? i read about angular material but i found that it doesn't have many options

Answer (score 1):

You can see this package, [angularCalendar 6](https://mattlewis92.github.io/angular-calendar/#/kitchen-sink) i think this plugin will full fill your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ngx-fullcalendar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-fullcalendar).

- It is easy to use and implement.
- You can install using commands provided in the link.
- Proper support and documentation is provided.

You can checkout this [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-fullcalendar-demo).

I don't know about your requirements so if you could mention in details your requirements we will be able to help you more properly.